# custom color for specific word: sublimetext

Tags: python, colors, scope, sublimetext

I've seen many solution, and tried many things, but still unable to change color of a specific word 'self' or other instead of 'self' as shown in sublime text.
[image: Sublime text]

N.B I've also tried a lot of scope names and changed their values to change the color.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html ?

Comment: Yes I did, but couldn't find any scope for this.

Comment: You find all the scopes at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html The scope for `self` looks to be `variable.language.python`

Comment: In the future, you can use **`Tools → Developer → Show Scope Name`** to show the full scope at the cursor. There are also plugins like [`ScopeHunter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) and [`ScopeAlways`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways) that can be very useful, especially if you are developing your own color scheme.

Comment: Wow! That was amazing.

Answer (score 0):

The color can be changed with "variable.language.python" scope.